Cloud-Init on Openstack fails, if security rules limit egress traffic
The Terraform-Code of compute instance:
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "my-server" {
  name            = "my-server"
  image_id        = "xxxx"
  security_groups = [ openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.my_sec_group.name ]
  user_data       = "${file("./cloud-config.yaml")}"
  config_drive    = true
  network { name = openstack_networking_network_v2.some_network.name }
}
resource "openstack_networking_secgroup_v2" "my_sec_group" {
  name                  = "my_sec_group"
  delete_default_rules  = true
}
resource "openstack_networking_secgroup_rule_v2" "allow_metadata_service" {
  direction         = "egress"
  ethertype         = "IPv4"
  remote_ip_prefix  = "169.254.169.254/32"
  security_group_id = openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.my_sec_group.id
}
# WORKS ONLY WITH SECURITY GROUP RULE allow_everything
resource "openstack_networking_secgroup_rule_v2" "allow_everything" {
  direction         = "egress"
  ethertype         = "IPv4"
  remote_ip_prefix  = "0.0.0.0/0"
  security_group_id = openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.my_sec_group.id
}

The cloud init:
#cloud-config
users:
    - name: root
      shell: /bin/bash
      hashed_passwd: xxxx
...

If I remove the security-group-rule allow_everything, the VM/cloud-init does NOT configure the networks properly.
What could be the reason that I need to allow 0.0.0.0/0? How can I limit the CIDR to be more secure and keep cloud init running?
